# How do I DYNAMICALLY cast in C# and return for a property

Tags: c#, casting

I've already read threads on the topic, but can't find a solution that fits.

I'm working on a drop-down list that takes an enum and uses that to populate itself.  i found a VB.NET one.  During the porting process, I discovered that it uses DirectCast() to set the type as it returns the SelectedValue.

See the original VB here:
http://jeffhandley.com/archive/2008/01/27/enum-list-dropdown-control.aspx

the gist is, the control has

```
Type _enumType; //gets set when the datasource is set and is the type of the specific enum
```

The `SelectedValue` property kind of looks like (remember, it doesn't work):

```
    public Enum SelectedValue  //Shadows Property
    {
        get
        {
            // Get the value from the request to allow for disabled viewstate
            string RequestValue = this.Page.Request.Params[this.UniqueID];

            return Enum.Parse(_enumType, RequestValue, true) as _enumType;
        }
        set
        {
            base.SelectedValue = value.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Now this touches on a core point that I think was missed in the other discussions.  In darn near every example, folks argued that `DirectCast` wasn't needed, because in every example, they statically defined the type.

That's not the case here.  As the programmer of the control, I don't know the type.  Therefore, I can't cast it.  Additionally, the following examples of lines won't compile because c# casting doesn't accept a variable.  Whereas VB's `CType` and `DirectCast` can accept Type T as a function parameter:

```
return Enum.Parse(_enumType, RequestValue, true);
```

or

```
return Enum.Parse(_enumType, RequestValue, true) as _enumType;
```

or

```
return  (_enumType)Enum.Parse(_enumType, RequestValue, true) ;
```

or

```
return Convert.ChangeType(Enum.Parse(_enumType, RequestValue, true), _enumType);
```

or

```
return CastTo<_enumType>(Enum.Parse(_enumType, RequestValue, true));
```

So, any ideas on a solution?  What's the .NET 3.5 best way to resolve this?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to cast to the right type... you only need to cast to Enum. That's the declared type of the property, after all:

```
return (Enum) Enum.Parse(_enumType, RequestValue, true);
```

(I'm not really sure why `Enum.Parse` isn't declared to return Enum itself, to be honest. It's not like it could be any other type.)

Comment: Once I slept on it, I came to the same conclusion.  Thanks!

Comment: that is not completely true

Comment: @JadaVonRuth: Without any more details, that's not particularly helpful. What exactly is not true, and in what way is it not true?

Comment: for instance when you want to make generic caster property (eg from db string to enum of various kinds given by type name in string) using implicit operators, having just enum instance will throw you an exception that types dont match

Comment: @JadaVonRuth: So you're not saying that the cast to `Enum` will fail - you're saying that sometimes you need a specific enum type. That's fine, but that's not what the question was asking for. What exactly have I said that is "not completely true" *in the context of what was being requested*?

Comment: Cast to enum will not fail but casting to generic enum is not dynamic cast, its just a cast

Comment: @JadaVonRuth: I'm afraid I'm not sure what you mean by that, but the OP has a property that is declared to return `Enum`. That should be all that's required, and the OP agreed with that in the first comment. So I think you're really talking about a different problem.

Comment: probably yeah, my bad, maybe i was mislead by title which suggest dynamic casting but example code does not, example code is just ordinary cast to basic Enum type, not his own types detected at runtime but a while ago I did need to resolve this and I have used something else, that's all

Answer (score 1):

- Generics
- return (Enum)Enum.Parse(_enumType, RequestValue, true);

The reason second one works is because you do not need to return value as the given type, just a value as type *Enum* even if it is the actual enumeration underneath.

Answer (score 0):

The best .NET 2.0/3.5 way to handle it is with generics.